# Modify MailChimp CampaignTemplateContent

Tags: mailchimp

I have just started to use mailchimp as a solution with an asp.net mvc application I am writing.

I am trying to use the mcapinet.codeplex.com wrapper.

I have created a template based on one of the precreated templates so I have all of the areas available to insert.

How do I insert insert my desired html into the template without affecting anything else? I basically just want to have a placeholder where I can dump in my own html.

Has someone done this?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This has to be one of the most confusing things I've tried to learn about MailChimp's API.  Forget everything you know about trying to use *|MERGE_TAGS|*.  You'll end up editing your template and using MC encoded form tags.

Here is an example: [Iterating over collection in mailchimp template via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940056/iterating-over-collection-in-mailchimp-template-via-api)